# How to change the weekends from Saturday/Sunday to other days

Tags: ngx-mydatepicker

https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker#options-attribute

weekend is not saturday/sunday
how can I fix the default weekend days?

Comment: You wanted to mark red different weekend days? Otherwise, I don't think it is possible yet by looking at their documentation. What you can do is disabling days.

Comment: yes, disabling days works!
Thank you.